# iOS - Calling bookmarkData() from a different thread returns an error

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I am using a download session task (AVDownloadTask) to download a stream. To do this, I use a `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask` in the init, the `delegateQueue` is set to `main`.

I create and resume session tasks from a separate thread:

```
func doSomething async {
   Task {
    //Task setup here resulting in a let called task
    task.resume()

   }
}
```

Now, in the delegate, I have:

```
   public func urlSession(
        _ session: URLSession,
        aggregateAssetDownloadTask: AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask,
        willDownloadTo location: URL
    ) {
        
        print("Location: \(location.path)")
        do {
            let data = (try location.bookmarkData())
            print("Generated data with length \(data.count)")
            
        } catch {
            print("Ooops, an error occurred:  \(error)")
        }
```

The problem is, when I run the code I get an error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file couldn’t be opened
> because it doesn’t exist."

I am not sure why this is the case. My code is basically exactly the same as a sample from Apple, however If I generate the task from a different thread on that sample, I can reproduce my error.

This leads me to believe, there is a problem (probably with security scoping, but doesn't make sense to me) when trying to access a URL from a different thread in order to generate a bookmark. Has anyone experience this? Any ideas how it can be fixed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` somewhere before accessing the resource? This is mandatory.

Comment: @vadian Thanks, even if I try, still no go. The first time I get the URL back from the OS is in the  `willDownloadTo` function in my listing above, if I try and do:

`location.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` this returns false and the error still persists.